# What supporting documents do I need to bring on a trip to the US on a previously used B1/B2 visa?

Tags: usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

I am a graduate student from India holding a valid B1/B2 US visa. I obtained it for attending a conference. Though I applied for B1 (conference/business) the visa type on my passport reads B1/B2. The only travel I have done with the visa is for the above mentioned conference and I did not overstay. I am planning to visit my girlfriend who is a graduate student at Brown University. I have booked both way tickets and I am visiting for ten days. I am planning to stay with her (at her apartment which she shares with her friend) during those ten days. What supporting documents do I need to produce to be allowed entry at my port of entry (which like the last time I traveled is JFK), especially regarding intent of return.

Comment: Evidence of your life in India would help, but the return tickets may bemore than enough, since you've already used the visa without overstaying.

Comment: @phoog Add an answer. Win a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Return ticket is sufficient document to show as a proof that you don't intent to overstay *(of course not overstaying in first visit will be an added advantage for you)*. Also, bring the travel insurance copy with you and let the Immigration officer clearly know you intent of second visit *(if asked)*.